# How to assign the values in a list to a column/row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to assign the values in a list to a column/row in python dataframe?

I could only do the vice versa with the command: `list_name = df.iloc[x, y]`. However, when I tried to command `df.iloc[x, y] = list_name`, I failed to convert the values in list_name to `df.iloc[x, y]`.

In this case, what should be the correct command to convert the values in list_name to `df.iloc[x, y]`?

Comment: could yo illustrate it on example? what is desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `iloc` indexing isn't designed for setting in quite as versatile a way as it is for getting. There is, however, a bit of a workaround if you want to have your row `x` and column `y` to be dynamic like in your example.

For the following, I've used the [*pandas.Dataframe* documentation example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) where we're starting with a dataframe like below.

```py
my_dict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
          {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]

df = pandas.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

### Step 1: Get the row

Quite simply, you can get your row by taking `df.iloc[x]`. If you had `x = 1`, with the above example, we'd get:

```py
> df.iloc[x]
a    100
b    200
c    300
d    400
```

When we have a row like this, we could get that value `300` by using the index `'c'`.

```py
> df.iloc[x]['c']
300
```

If all you have is your column index, however, you'll need to fetch this name first.

### Step 2: Get the column name

To convert your index `y` into a column name, we can use the [*dataframe* `axes` property](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.axes.html#pandas.DataFrame.axes), like follows:

```py
> y = 2
> df.axes[1][y]
c
```

### Step 3: Put it together

Now, if we want to use `x` and `y` to reference a particular entry in the dataframe, we can do that by first getting the `row` and then the `column` like:

```py
row = df.iloc[x]
column = df.axes[1][y]
row[column] = desired_value
```

Or, if you want to one-line it:

```py
df.iloc[x][df.axes[1][y]]
```

### Full Example

Here's a full example of this in action.

```py
import pandas

x = 1
y = 2

my_dict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
          {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]

df = pandas.DataFrame(my_dict)

desired_value = 999

row = df.iloc[x]
column = df.axes[1][y]
row[column] = desired_value

print(df)
```

That print statement at the end gives us:

```
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   999   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
```

Note the `999` we set with `row[column] = desired_value`.